# multiple aggregations in a kafka stream application

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a KStream created from a an input topic.
1. On this KStream, I am doing a groupByKey and then a windowed aggregation operation
2. After that, in my code, I again use the same KStream as above, do a map operation to make some changes to the key & value, and then do another windowed aggregation operation.

All my windowed operation are on a tumbling window of 30 secs. My observation is that the second aggregation is starting about 30 secs after the first aggregation. Is there a way to parallelize them ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "is starting about 30 secs after the first aggregation" ? Wall-clock (ie, runtime) delay, or even-time?

Comment: It is wall clock time.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "is starting about 30 secs after the first aggregation"? Do you mean:

- A delay according to processing-time/wall-clock time (the time you happen to process an input event, regardless of when this event actually occurred in the real world), or
- A delay according to event-time (the time when an input event actually occurred in the real world)?

It's expected that the second aggregation is delayed (according to wall-clock time) because the data must be repartitioned after the `map()` to compute the correct window aggregation, which takes a bit of time.

The structure of your program will be something like this:

```
KStream -+-> group() -> agg()
         |
         +-> map() -> to() -> REPARTITION-TOPIC -> KStream -> group() -> agg()
```

There is nothing you can do about this, but it should also not be a problem, as it will not affect the correctness of your result.